# Is there a way to force waiting for the end of a java process to end in Scala or Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

In a Scala app, deployed through Spark, I have a code line which calls to a Java function executing native C++ code through a JNI. This call takes time, and if it is not the only one of his kind running, a resource usage conflict appears with a `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated`.

Here's the call, and it's scope :

```
[spark RDD].mapPartitionsWithIndex(f = (index: Int, it: Iterator[Row]) => {
  val sourceData: String = it.mkString()

  val result: List[List[String]] = new WrapperClass(sourceData, [misc parameters).getResult

  [wrinting result to a file]
}).take(1)
```

My `WrapperClass.getResult`, very simple, looks like this :

```
[java call related variables initialization]

UnitexJni.execUnitexTool("UnitexTool {InstallLingResourcePackage -p " + appliedPkg + " -x " + resDir + "} " + "{" + runScriptCmd + "} " + "{InstallLingResourcePackage -p " + appliedPkg + " -x " + resDir + " --uninstall}")

[retrieving, formatting and returning result]
```

The `UnitexJni.execUnitexTool()` is the java call.

So I would like to know if there is a way to force to wait until the end of this process before calling it over agin using Scala, Java or Spark functionality.

Comment: Add a code snippet to your question that shows how you run this script command with JNI please.

Comment: I did not include it at first time, because the line calling the JNI is very specific, so I'll put it here :

`UnitexJni.execUnitexTool("UnitexTool {InstallLingResourcePackage -p " + appliedPkg + " -x " + resDir + "} " +
      "{" + runScriptCmd + "} " +
      "{InstallLingResourcePackage -p " + appliedPkg + " -x " + resDir + " --uninstall}")`


With the RunScript command also being a specific string to send to the JNI.

Though, as far as I have tested, this call does what it is supposed to. It is the Spark ordonancement which causes task conflict.

Comment: Assume you run a shell script from Scala, Then you need to force Scala not to do any other thing till this script finished to avoid the conflict. Correct?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud
Correct.

Comment: @OlivierGRACIANNE Please have a look for my answer below

Comment: Can you also provide the enclosing scope of the UnitexJni Call? As far I can see this call should be blocking so the execution of later commands should wait for this unless you have wrapped it in a Future or something else which would run async. You can also edit you question and add the code there for better formatting.

Comment: @MeiSign Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: Let me recap to see if I understood your usecase. You want to run the UnitexJni tool for each row in your Spark RDD but UnitexJni does not support parallel execution. You need to execute it for all records sequentially and wait until the previous execution has finished. 
If that assumptions are correct, I am not sure if Spark is a good choice here because Spark is designed for distributed/parallel execution. You use Spark to prepare your dataset as a normal Scala List and map this list with your UnitexJni Tool. Native scala lists are mapped sequentially.

Comment: @MeiSign You are almost correct. UnitexJni supports parrallel execution, as it's use is thread safe (according to my talks with it's dev team). I want to run it in parrallel on each partition of the RDD created. But it seems that if one exectuor starts multiple call in the same thread (which is what is going on right now as I'm running Spark localy), I get a `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated`. So having n threads running it at the same time is ok, but I wanna make sure that one thread run only one of these processes at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I think I can’t help with this complex problem without any debugging. My gut feeling is that it is not threadsafe. I would try to go ahead with building a subset of my data as a list and process it sequentially to see if it works without any errors. If yes you can go from there and experiment with spark settings to limit the threads/cores per executor. If it doesn’t run sequentially it might be a problem with resource allocation or resources that haven’t been closed properly?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is not 100% thread safe. There's something that try (maybe it is a little mistake) to acces another thread's resource and generate the stack smashing. But I have constraints too. So my wish is to avoid any situation that can generate any error. That's why I want to entirely control the execution of one of these calls.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sys.process._` You will pass the `shell` script to the below process function with the script path. Also, you need to handle the shell script to have a return code. For example, `If 0 success else failed`. Please take care of the `!` at the end of the line. You could also check more details to run quick command lines from this [tutorial](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-execute-exec-external-system-commands-in-scala)

```
import scala.sys.process.Process
val externalShellScript = Process("sh", Seq(scriptPath)).!    
  if (externalShellScript != 0) {
    throw new Exception(
      "Error in executing external shell script from " + scriptPath)
  }
```

The Spark job will not continue unless this process finish. Below is simple shell script and the output.

```
touch test.txt
echo "any massage"
```

output in the console will be

```
any massage
```

Comment: That would the perfect answer if I was to use a shell script. But actually, it's a call to a java function executing native C++ code through a JNI. So my question would rather be can I fork a java process and actively wait it's return code.

Thanks for the tip though. 'Will be useful on another thing I'm on.

Comment: I can’t understand your actual question, You need to run Java code from Scala and wait till it finish?

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: But in Scala you can import and call Java function from Library or dependency. I think your problem is related to the dependency.

Comment: I know this. I'm actually importing the dependency without problem. The point is that I am not sure about how Scala/Spark handle the native C++ long process going on under the java call. So I'd like to have direct control on it from hosting code.